# Videos from DAM assets are not playing inline when used inside carousel

Tags: aem

All the images are coming up from DAM assets in carousel component but videos(from DAM assets) are not coming inline with them.

I have tried including autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto" with image tag and I guess video tag should be automatically picked when it encounters a video. How to bring about the same?

```html
<div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="5" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 500px; position: relative; left: -2500px; top: 0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1;" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide05" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control05">
   <a href="javascript:;" class="js-carousel-item" tabindex="0">
      <figure>
         <img src="/content/dam/global-abc/mcos/benefra/nl/custom/product-images/25-nl-107855/y2mate.com - we_are_ufs_supporting_you_unilever_food_solutions_arabia_kDoAaokWuYU_360p.mp4">
      </figure>
   </a>
</div>
```

Video from DAM assets should play inline with other images in the carousel.

Comment: you are adding mp4 file inside img tag, are you sure you are doing it correctly?

Comment: As @SumantaPakira already pointed out, you should not put the video in an `<img>` tag, but rather in an `<video>` tag. But even then this might not be the best idea, since all modern browsers move to a "no autoplay" default setting. That means that soon videos that "autoplay" might not work anymore for your use case.

Comment: Since this video will be a part of carousel along with many other images, how can I get the dc:format value of  the DAM asset metadata, based on which I can add the 'video' tag for video asset.